# Creating Thumbnail Image from Video using FFMPEG is not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ffmpeg

I am trying to create thumbnail image for uploaded video with [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in ASP.NET Core as follows:

```
private void GetThumbnail(IFormFile file)
{
        var fileName = CreateEmployeeViewModel.Video.FileName;
        var webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var filePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "videos", fileName);

        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        var thumbnailImageName = fileName.Replace(fileExtension, ".jpg");
        var thumbnailImagePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "thumbnails", thumbnailImageName);

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        string arguments = $"-i {filePath} -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 {thumbnailImagePath}";

        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe");
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        try
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            process.WaitForExit(5000);
            process.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Log error.
        }

}
```

It's not showing any error but it's also not generating the thumbnail image. am I missing anything please?

Note: if I execute the above configuration from command line its works!

Comment: `arguments` starts with `"ffmpeg...` - are you sure about that? BTW, it won't throw an exception. You need to check the exit code.

Comment: @Fildor I have also tried removing this but did not work.

Comment: @Fildor All exit code are 0 which are for debugging.

Comment: Can try to check if there are useful info in error output using `string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: @FeiHan I am getting permission denied error for accessing the  video file. How can I run the  exe as admin?

Comment: `getting permission denied error for accessing the video file` For testing purpose, you can try to set the folder/file permissions for Everyone, then check if it works or another error occurs.

Comment: @FeiHan  I have set folder permission for everyone but same error again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xabe.ffmpeg
https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/

The below will get a snapshot of video you're uploading

```
string output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".png");

IConversion conversion = await 
FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Snapshot(inputMp4Path, output, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
IConversionResult result = await conversion.Start();
```

You specify your format in the output string.
You read more in their documentation